# Recording the live streming

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3, audio-recording

Currently I'm playing the live radio stream using MPMoviePlayerController. I want to record & save the radio programs in my application.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do so using AVFoundation.

1. Initial an instance of [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using you stream url
2. Use [AVAssetReader](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetReader) to read the stream bytes
3. Use [AVAssetWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to write bytes to new file.

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into the audio portion, I made a sample app that can record say, Pandora while it's running. Hope this helps! https://github.com/casspangell/AudioMic